# How to use .htaccess to do a redirect from /login to /login/login.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, debian

I'm trying to use .htaccess or any other method so that when a user types in

https://websitename/login

it will redirect to

https://websitename/login/login.html

I'm using apache2 on a debian 9.x server and have tried using mod_rewrite and RewriteRule. Neither are working.

Here is what I have currently:

```
RewriteOptions inherit 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login$ "https\:\/\/websitename\.com\/login\/login\.html" [R=301,L]
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since /login/ is an existent directory on your server, you need to trun off directory slash to redirect **/login** (without a traling slash)  to **/login.html** .

```
RewriteEngine on

DirectorySlash off
RewriteRule ^login$ /login/login.html [L,R]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will do what you need:

```
RewriteOptions inherit 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://websitename.com/login/login.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this seems to just redirect me to the login directory. Which shows a file tree for the folder